# Incorrect captcha and empty fields in form in django application

Tags: python, django, forms, field, captcha

In my django application - I have a view of the form. The problem is that when I have the wrong captcha, other data (name, e-mail, message) are empty, and should be filled with the entered data.

**view.py**

```
def contact(request):
    form = ContactForm(request.POST)
    key = CaptchaStore.generate_key()
    image_url = captcha_image_url(key)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data.__delitem__('val')
        data.__delitem__('check1')
        data.__delitem__('check2')
        data.__delitem__('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
        msg = '\n'.join(['%s %s' % (i, data[i]) for i in data if data[i]])
        try:
            mail_managers(_('Contact Form'), msg)
            contact_confirm(form.cleaned_data['email'])
        except Exception:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'key': key, 'image_url': image_url,
                'message': _('Sorry there was an error while sending email.')}))
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': True, 'message': _('Message was sent')}))

    message = ", ".join(["%s: %s"%x for x in form.errors.iteritems()]).replace("__all__:","")

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'success': False, 'message': message,
                                    'key': key, 'image_url': image_url}))
```

Comment: There's rarely any reason to call double-underscore methods like `__delitem__` directly. You should call `del data['val']`, or `data.pop('val', None)` if the item may not exist. And you should never catch all Exceptions: just catch the ones you know you can deal with.

Comment: In any case, this code doesn't appear to render the form at all, so I don't know what it has to do with the form fields appearing empty.